# artifactory/api/security/groups does not seem to accept the includeUsers=true parameter

Tags: artifactory

I'm trying to retrieve all users from the user groups of Artifactory, using the following command:
curl -u : -X GET -d 'includeUsers=true' https:///artifactory/api/security/groups

But I only get the groups, not the users. I'm on Artifactory version 6.14.1. The parameter (includedUsers=true) was added in 6.13.

Any idea what is wrong?

thanks,
Filip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Couple of things:

1. Seems like the includeUsers only works when fetching a specific group's details.
2. You should be passing the includeUsers as a query param, not with '-d' which is meant to be used with POST/PUT/PATCH methods

For example:

```
curl -u : -X GET "https:///artifactory/api/security/groups/<a group name>?includeUsers=true
```

Comment: OK, it works to get the users for one group. But according to https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-GetGroups it looks like we should also be able to get users for all groups.

Comment: Might be a problem with the wiki page. Regardless, you can write a simple job to fetch the list of groups, and then loop on each group and get the users for that group.

Comment: It does not make a lot of sense to return all users to all groups in a single API call since the response might contain millions of records. Seems like the wiki was updated...